# How to apply vertical aligning for div children by using TranslateY IE8 analog (matrix)?

Tags: html, css, quotes

I am trying to adapt the solution from this question: [Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) (answer by Neftas)

```
<html>
     <head>
       <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div style="height: 100px; border: solid;">
            <div style = "position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">This is vertically aligned text within a div</div>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

This works fine in modern IEs, but not work in IE8.
[image]

I found this http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/ converter that converts TranslateY(-50%) call into matrix.

So, I made my code in that way:

```
 <html>
     <head>
       <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div style="height: 100px; border: solid;">
            <div style = "position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');">This is vertically aligned text within a div</div>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

But the inner div still stays in wrong vertical position, like matrix were never applied.
[image]

P.S. I know about `display: table-cell` but this leads to another bugs in IE8.

Comment: Thank you, but those answers aren't on my question. Those are about displaying quotes, but mine about setting style. `SizingMethod=&quot;auto expand&quot;` of course this will never work.

Comment: @Quentin - Please, reopen my question. It's a different case of "out of quotation marks" problem.

Comment: Both questions are about putting quote characters in attribute values. It doesn't matter what the attribute is used for. The problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: "Something like this will never work: `SizingMethod=&quot;auto expand&quot;` " — Yes it will. The HTML parser will replace `&quot;` with `"` before passing it to the CSS parser.

Comment: @Quentin - I really tested it, but I see no effect of this transformation.

Comment: That is still how you fix the problem you asked about. Having looked at [the documentation for `filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it turns out that you misdiagnosed your problem in the first place … you shouldn't have quotes around the entire value at all!

Comment: @Quentin - ok, thank you for answers. The transformation no works even in this way: `-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');`, so it might be something wrong with the values.

Comment: What browser (and version) are you testing in?

Comment: I testing it in IE8. Trying to solve vertical aligning by: `<html>
     <head>
       <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div style="height: 100px; border: solid;">
            <div style = "position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');">This is vertically aligned text within a div</div>
        </div>
     </body>
 </html>` and this http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/ since IE8 does not supports transform.

Comment: Well, if you edit the question to focus on the actual problem, it could be reopened.

Comment: @Quentin - I totally edited my question.